# How to deal with long list of return values and not face IndentationError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function in Python that returns 5 items (I didn't develop the function so I cannot change it). If I want to give meaningful names to the return values, it will be a long line and it will exceed the 80 characters per line recommendation. So I wrote it like this:

```
encoded_en,
    forward_h_en, forward_c_en,
    backward_h_en, backward_c_en = encoder(embedding)
```

But then, I faced the `indentation` error:

```
File "<ipython-input-28-5947292b462a>", line 20
    forward_h_en, forward_c_en
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

What is the proper way to deal with such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
(encoded_en,
    forward_h_en, forward_c_en,
    backward_h_en, backward_c_en) = range(5)
print(encoded_en)  # 0
```